# Предотвратить нажатия во время авторизации Google

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-account

Как обновление [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941880/google-signinintent-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-resultcode/941945#941945)

```
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, AUTH_REQUEST);

...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == AUTH_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { // результат не ок!

                    Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
                    try {
                   
                        GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
                    } catch (ApiException e) {...}
}
...
```

После **startActivityForResult** стартует активность с выбором аккаунта, после выбора- экран затемняется на (0,5-1сек) что бы подключится. Если в этот момент нажать по экрану, то

```
 resultCode  == RESULT_CANCELED
```

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16

Вопрос: как предотвратить реакцию на нажатие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего сделать нельзя. Вы запускаете стороннее приложение над которым контроля у вас нет. Вам надо вручную обрабатывать `resultCode != RESULT_OK` и выводить юзеру сообщение что авторизация прервана.